# Applying SSL globally on IIS - need advice

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

I'm doing some work on a website that currently has a subscription based SSL, but the SSL is only applied to a select few pages - Login, Checkout, etc. We want to apply the SSL globally, so it covers the whole website.

I don't have access to the hosting panel, and am not familiar with IIS. The company/person that manages the hosting is implying that this is a difficult and time consuming job (that they have to do it manually for every page - which sounds bizarre to me). From my own experience on Linux/Apache hosting, I know I can achieve this in just a few minutes.

Therefore, can you assist me by confirming whether there would be any circumstances whereby this process wouldn't be fairly quick and easy. Should it not just be a case of setting the SSL up for the domain and then forcing all traffic across to https via a redirect?

Look forward to hearing your advice.

Kind regards!

Comment: "The company/person that manages the hosting is implying that this is a difficult and time consuming job (that they have to do it manually for every page"? That's not true for IIS as well. Challenge them or find another hosting vendor.

Comment: Thank you! What you have said is exactly what I believe too, but I needed to hear it from someone with IIS experience. I understand the process, but do not like challenging others until I have certain things confirmed for me first. I have some experience of this, just not specific to IIS. The next step is to request a proper explanation of their proposed method/process and see how that aligns with the way it's explained in countless online tutorials (which all make perfect sense to me). Thanks again!